# Use PHP to List Minecraft Player Usernames on a Server

Tags: php, python, ping, minecraft

I have been searching around for a solution to listing the usernames of players that are currently online on a Minecraft server. My client doesn't want to use Plugins so this is sightly more tricky.

I have see DinnerBone use Python on his [website](http://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/status/) to list online players with their usernames. I was wondering if this is possible to do and if not, does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to what I was looking for. If anyone else wants to know for future reference, I used [xPaw's](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query) PHP classes that use RCON to query the IP of the server and return various bits of information (in this case the usernames that are currently on the server).

I used the [MinecraftQuery_Simple.php](https://github.com/xPaw/PHP-Minecraft-Query/blob/master/MinecraftQuery_Simple.php) file. Then it's as simple as defining the server address/IP and (in my case):

```
    <?PHP
        if(($Players = $Query->GetPlayers()) !== false) {
            foreach($Players as $Player) {
            echo "<img src=https://minotar.net/avatar/".$Player."/74.png>
                  <p>".$Player."</p>";
            }
        } 
    ?>
```

Hope someone finds this as useful as I did in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it can be done. You should read up on [PHP's Sockets API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.sockets.php).
You'll then just have to figure out the correct message to send and parse the received result.

Just keep in mind that not all hosts will allow doing such things based on security settings, as it can in theory be abused to things most hosts don't want you to do (like running game or chat servers and the like).